# How to drop buffer during a certain time in gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: debugging, gstreamer

I'm working on the debugging of gstreamer applications throught execution traces. I've the following pipeline to decode a mp4 file, I'm using `identity drop-probability` to drop packets in the pipeline. I do so to simulate the losing of packets in the stream.

```
gst-launch filesrc location=data/pub_Irma.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! identity drop-probability=0.5 ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

this pipeline does **drops 50 percent of buffer going to ffdec_h264**. The problem is that It is monotone, and finally It looks like regular behaviour. I want the same behaviour but only during a certain duration and from a certain timestamp.

It will be like saying **drops 50 percent of buffer going to ffdec_h264, starting at 10 sec and finishing at 15s**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to write a little application and use a pad probe. the probe callback can drop the buffer. It can also look at the buffer ts to decide whether to drop or not.